# What can I do as OpenShift user?

Tags: openshift, root-access

I'm currently using a virtual server and want to try [OpenShift](http://openshift.redhat.com/) out. But I'm not really getting yet, how it works. Do I get a root access to my "webspace"? Can I set up the server OS (e.g. Debian 7)? Can I install/uninstall software (nginx, PHP 5.5, PHP Code Sniffer PEAR package etc.)? Can I use one gear for multiple websites?

Comment: A related discussion : [New Relic requires root access on Openshift machine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28185384/320399)

Answer (score 1):

It not clear by your line of questioning what portion of [OpenShift](http://openshift.redhat.com/) you are not understanding, so I will try and lay out the architecture and provide documentation to get you started.

OpenShift is a Red Hat developed product (so its going to be easiest to get started on RHEL or Fedora), but it can also run on other Linux systems (however you may need to piece meal the components together, but it can be done).

- This is talked about in [building your own live cd](https://www.openshift.com/wiki/build-your-own-paas-from-the-openshift-origin-livecd-using-liveinst) on the community site, however has [not been done](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/can-i-install-openshift-origin-live-cd-on-debian-or-ubuntu) for you by the OpenShift community.

There are two starting places for OpenShift, and they dependon on what you are trying to use openshift for? As a PaaS hosting solution, or PaaS hosted solution?

For a PaaS hosting solution a good starting point is to look at the [Origin](https://www.openshift.com/products/origin) page as it provides VM's and install instructions, for OpenShift's Community product.

Because OpenShift is a PaaS solution these components (see Architecture Links), when cobbled together provide users with an application space (which they do not have root access to).

- https://www.openshift.com/products/architecture
- https://www.openshift.com/wiki/architecture-overview

As the administrator for the box you would have (root access) but your end users would not.

For a PaaS hosted solution a good starting place for OpenShift is [OpenShift Online](https://www.openshift.com/products/online) which is Red Hat's Hosted solution for the OpenShift Origin project.

- Get started by [Creating an Acount](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/account/new)

With an online account you can get started using the hosted solution very quickly by trying some of the [quickstarts](https://www.openshift.com/quickstarts). Be sure to read the full set of [OpenShift Documentation](https://www.openshift.com/developers/documentation) as well as install the [client tools](https://www.openshift.com/developers/rhc-client-tools-install)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and links! I still have my questions (to OpenShift Online): Can I chose the OS (e.g. Debian 7)? Can I set up, install, and uninstall software (e.e. web server)? Can I use one gear for multiple websites? I know, I have to read the docu and to understand, how it works. But it would also be nice to get answers to these questions, before I start working with OpenShift.

Comment: OS - No reason the RPMs can't be rebuilt as DEBs, for other sofware - yes, for multiple sites yes with a custom cartridge.