# New Relic requires root access on Openshift machine

Tags: openshift, newrelic, newrelic-platform

- I have an Application on Openshift and I just added New Relic add-on
- New Relic asks for setting up Server and configuration is listed as
  [image]

However, I could not get root access , I tried

```
\> sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.newrelic.com/pub/newrelic/el5/i386/newrelic-repo-5-3.noarch.rpm
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied

> su - root
bash: /bin/su: Permission denied

> sudo su
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied
```

How do I setup New Relic on my Openshift box?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You're not allowed root access on OpenShift Online so you can't install the New Relic package globally. Application code on OpenShift operates in a sandbox environment—a *gear*. (More on the OpenShift architecture [here](http://www.openshift.org/documentation/oo_system_architecture_guide.html).)

So to use New Relic on OpenShift you must make it work inside within a gear by creating an OpenShift cartridge. (That is, unless you can find an existing New Relic cartridge already made by someone else.) [This blog post](https://blog.openshift.com/new-openshift-cartridge-format-part-1/) does a great job explaining the restrictions of software operating in a cartridge and goes through an example of making Apache work within a cartridge.

Answer (score 2):

New relic only currently supports a java agent cartridge according to this link:
https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/deploying-new-relic-on-openshift/10522

I would seem that if you want any other platform you will need to contact OpenShift for support.

Comment: I followed that link you provided and found the third party New Relic / Openshift cartridge on that site very useful for getting my Java app monitored.  I'll link it here directly for others: https://github.com/zokusai/openshift-cartridge-newrelic-agent