# java.net.BindException When Creating ServerSocket on Tomcat 7 on OpenShift

Tags: java, openshift, serversocket

I was trying to launch a application on Openshift which listens to a port via ServerSocket.

```
ServerSocket  = new ServerSocket(8080);
```

But it failed with the following error message:

```
java.net.BindException: Permission denied
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)...
```

I've tried to change the port from 8080 to 8000, and then to 15000. But none of them worked.

I did search intensively on the Internet. However, I still cannot find a solution. Does anyone have a clue?

---

## 2015-12-29 edited

Proposed Reason:

> Openshift allows gears to bind to port 8080. But Tomcat has already
>   bound 8080. So, my application is disallowed binding to the same port.

Proposed Solution:

> Use DIY Cart instead.  But it seems that Openshift only allows
>   external client to connect with http://, https://, ws:// and wss://
>   protocol ([OpenShift Developer Guide](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html)). Applications should be modified
>   to handle these protocols.

[Ungarida](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34503062/5716098) confirmed the solution and provided [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/online/cartridge_specification_guide/exposing_services.html).

Comment: From the error message you don't have a permission to bind socket. Try with root user also check the firewall.

Comment: I don't think I can get root access on OpenShift, as SFERICH from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797239/what-can-i-do-as-openshift-user) suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is the only solution, take a look to this [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/online/cartridge_specification_guide/exposing_services.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think using DIY cart may be a solution.

Openshift allows gears to bind to port 8080. I suspect that Tomcat has already bound 8080. So, my application is disallowed bind to the same port.

I've tried DIY cart and I got no exception. But it seems that Openshift only allows external client to connect with http://, https://, ws:// and wss:// protocol [(OpenShift Developer Guide)](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html).  I have to modify my application to handle these protocols.

Does anyone know other solution?